Get Full profile details from LinkedIn APIs
I am trying to get Skill, Education, Certificate, Course, Projects from my or any other LinkedIn profile whoever registered to my app.
Based on the documentation online and StackOverflow questions, it seems like we will need r_liteprofile, r_basicprofile, r_fullprofile, r_emailaddress, r_contactinfo, r_organization_social, etc scopes. I would like to access the fields listed in profile section - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/education?context=linkedin%2Fconsumer%2Fcontext
But there is no documentation officially stating how to get access to these scopes.
In some of the documentation, it was written that all of these scopes are deprecated.
Below are the scopes I could see in my account,

When I tried to fetch details I got only the below fields -
{
    "sub": "xx",
    "email_verified": true,
    "name": "xx",
    "locale": {
        "country": "US",
        "language": "en"
    },
    "given_name": "xx",
    "family_name": "xx",
    "email": "xx@gmail.com",
    "picture": ""
}

I checked scopes for all the projects listed in the apps page, but couldn't find them.
Can someone please help here?
